# How to close an event on navigating to different Tab or window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Suppose i am trying to make an portal for Online Test on my angular application, And i want close and end the session on navigating (opening new tab or window) to different Window. Is it possible to do so with any JavaScript or J Query function? 
Or to restrict users from opening new screen Unless they submit the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `blur` event:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    // end session
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Works well for me.

Comment: Hi @shricharanbhat if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.